# Prometheus - debugging slow query

Tags: prometheus

The following query is taking more than 1 min, and timing out. It's made from Grafana:

```
/grafana/api/datasources/proxy/2/api/v1/query_range?
  query=rate(rmq_publish{name="app1" }
     [5m])&start=1520264038&end=1520264338&step=30
```

The behaviour is same both with rate and irate, and with step as 2s or 30s.

I think the number of samples for this metric with different labels is large. How do I find this out?

Any tips for profiling this query to find out why it's taking too long to process?

Answer (score 2):

> I think the number of samples for this metric with different labels is large. How do I find this out?

You can find out the number of samples by using the `count` operator:

```
count by (__name__)({__name__="your_metric_name"})
```

> Any tips for profiling this query to find out why it's taking too long to process?

The query performance depends mostly on the size of your data. I would recommend you first investigate the data size before diving into promql profiling.

An easy workaround is to pre-record your query via Prometheus' rule recording: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/#recording-rules

Comment: Thanks. One quick question: the query performance depends mostly on the size of your data overall or number of samples of the metrics involved in the query?

Comment: Number of samples.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus query performance depends on the following factors:

1. The number of unique time series the query needs to select on the given time range. This number can be determined with the following query, which must be sent to [/api/v1/query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries) endpoint:

```
count(last_over_time(series_selector[lookbehind_window]))
```

where:

- `series_selector` is the [time series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) used in the original query
- `lookbehind_window` is the time range for the original query. See [time duration format](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-durations).

For example, the following query returns the number of time series, which need to be selected on a week-long time range for `rmq_publish{name="app1"}` series selector:

```
count(last_over_time(rmq_publish{name="app1"}[7d]))
```

Note that simple `count(rmq_publish{name="app1"})` may return much lower number than `count(last_over_time(rmq_publish{name="app1"}[7d]))` if matching time series are under [churn rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/FAQ.html#what-is-high-churn-rate).

2. The number of raw samples the query needs to select. This number can be obtained via the following query sent to `/api/v1/query` endpoint:

```
sum(count_over_time(series_selector[lookbehind_window]))
```

For example, the following query returns the total number of raw samples the query `rate(rmq_publish{name="app1"}[5m]` needs to process when being performed on the 7 days time range:

```
sum(count_over_time(rmq_publish{name="app1"}[7d]))
```

[This article](https://valyala.medium.com/how-to-optimize-promql-and-metricsql-queries-85a1b75bf986) contains more details on how to determine the root cause of slow PromQL query with possible solutions on how to improve query performance.